# Index Mapping for nested json for schema registry

Tags: elasticsearch, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I have mapped and successfully indexed json files of different formats. But this particular json file which is created from schema registry is weird and i am unable to crack the mapping for it. I have also referenced a lot of articles, but of no help.

Please find below mapping and json file which i am trying to index. It does get indexed, i am not getting the output as i want it to look like.

Mapping:

```
    "mappings":
            {
                "_doc":
                    {
                        "dynamic" : "true",
                        "properties":
                            {
                                "schema":
                                    {
                                        "type": "nested",
                                        "properties":
                                            {
                                            "type":
                                                {
                                                    "type": "text"

                                                },
                                            "name":
                                                {
                                                    "type": "text"

                                                },
                                            "namespace":
                                                {
                                                    "type": "text"

                                                },
                                            "fields":
                                                {
                                                    "type": "nested",
                                                    "properties":
                                                        {
                                                            "name":
                                                                {
                                                                    "type": "text"

                                                                },
                                                            "type":
                                                                {
                                                                    "type": "text"

                                                                }

                                                        }

                                                }

                                        }

                                },
                                "deleted":
                                    {
                                        "type": "boolean"

                                    },
                                "subject":
                                    {
                                        "type": "text"

                                    },
                                "id":
                                    {
                                        "type": "integer"

                                    },
                                "version":
                                    {
                                        "type": "integer"

                                    }

                            }

                    }

            }
```

the json file looks like.

```
{
"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"F3253\",\"namespace\":\"ADMIN\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"table\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"op_type\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"op_ts\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"current_ts\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"pos\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"primary_keys\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":\"string\"}]},{\"name\":\"before\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"row\",\"namespace\":\"\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"C1\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"C2\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"C3\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"C4\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"C5\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"C6\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"C7\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"C8\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940003025\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940003026\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940003027\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"C800502536\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005001\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"C536870914\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"C536870918\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"C536870919\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"C536870920\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005060\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005061\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005063\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005064\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005082\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005083\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005085\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005089\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005092\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005093\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005094\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005095\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005096\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005097\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005099\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005100\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005101\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005102\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005104\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005105\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005106\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005107\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005108\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005109\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005110\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005111\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005112\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005113\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005114\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005115\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005122\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005123\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005124\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005125\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005126\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005127\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005128\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005129\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005130\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005141\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005142\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005143\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005144\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005145\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005509\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005510\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005511\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005512\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005513\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005514\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005515\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005518\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005519\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005520\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005521\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940005522\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940007513\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008202\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008203\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940006953\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008052\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008053\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008054\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008055\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008056\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008057\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008058\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008060\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008061\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008062\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008063\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008064\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008065\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008066\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008067\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008068\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008069\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008070\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008071\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008073\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008075\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008076\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940008352\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009041\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009042\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009043\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009044\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009045\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009046\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009047\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009048\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009049\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009050\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009051\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009052\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009053\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009054\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009055\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009056\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009057\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009058\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009059\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009062\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009277\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009278\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009279\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009280\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009281\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009282\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009295\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009296\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009297\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009760\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009761\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009762\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009763\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009764\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009765\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009766\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009767\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009772\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010169\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940007906\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940007907\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940007909\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009512\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009513\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009514\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009516\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009517\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009519\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009520\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009521\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009528\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009530\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009532\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940009533\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010354\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010355\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010356\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010357\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010358\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010359\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010360\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010361\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010362\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010363\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010364\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010365\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010366\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010367\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010370\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010375\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010376\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010377\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010378\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010380\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010382\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010390\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010391\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010392\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010394\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010395\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010396\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010404\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010878\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010879\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010880\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010881\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010882\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010883\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010884\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940010885\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"C800502452\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011556\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011557\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011558\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011559\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011560\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011561\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011562\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011563\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011564\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011565\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011566\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011571\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011572\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011573\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011574\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011575\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011576\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011577\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011578\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011579\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011580\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011581\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011582\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011583\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011584\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011585\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011586\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011587\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011621\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011623\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011629\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011634\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011635\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011636\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011637\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011638\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011639\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011640\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011641\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011642\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011665\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011666\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011672\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011815\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011816\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011821\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011822\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011823\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011824\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011825\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011826\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011827\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940011828\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012160\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012161\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012162\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012163\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012164\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012165\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012169\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012170\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012171\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012172\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012648\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012649\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012650\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940012651\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940013752\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940013753\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]},{\"name\":\"F940013754\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940013755\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940013756\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940013757\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940013758\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940014875\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"]},{\"name\":\"F940014876\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]}],\"connect.name\":\"row\"}]},{\"name\":\"after\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"row\"]}],\"connect.name\":\"ADMIN.F3253\"}",
"deleted": false,
"subject": "app-goldenGate-ass-ADMIN_F3253-value",
"id": 157,
"version": 1
```

}

I want something where the index shows

metadata.schema.**namespace** : ....

metadata.schema.**name** : ....

Not like the below as i am currently getting -

> metadata.schema   {"type":"record","**name**":"Envelope","**namespace**":Bla

Comment: `schema` is only a string, not a nested object. You need to parse that JSON into an object that you'd expect to index (perhaps using Kafka Streams on the Schema Registry topic)